# Relicensing code from answers

Tags: discussion, licensing

Part of the discussion about packaging some of the TikZ answers into a LaTeX package has centred on the issue of licensing the code.  Contributions here are licensed under a CC license (see links at the bottom of the page) which isn't the best for software: even the people behind the CC licenses [do not recommend](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F) its use for software.  LaTeX packages are usually licensed under the LPPL (see http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/), but other free licenses such as GNU GPL (see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) are sometimes used.  Exactly how the various licenses interact is ... complicated.
As the goons memorably quipped,

> It's all rather confusing, really.

However, the people who answer questions retain copyright on their material and are therefore free to relicense it as they wish.

In the ensuing discussions, some have felt that the simplest thing to do is to issue a blanket declaration saying that repackaging and relicensing of their code written on this site is allowed.  The purpose of this question is to allow people to publicly state what terms their code is released under.  Note that this is *in addition* to the standard SE license terms and is designed to make it easier for people to repackage answers as desired.

There are many open source licenses out there.  Some useful links are:

- The [list at gnu](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html), including the FSF's beliefs on which are compatible with GPL.
- The [list at CTAN](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/licenses.html), including CTAN's beliefs on which are free.

Here are some comments to bear in mind when choosing how to relicense your code:

1. The purpose of this is to make it **easier** for others to build on your work.
2. GPL is probably the most popular for software in general, and LPPL for TeX packages specifically.
3. The LPPL and GPL [are incompatible](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLIncompatibleLicenses).
4. It is possible to license code under several licenses, with the choice of license being for the user to decide.  Indeed, any declaration here is *in addition* to the CC-BY-SA license that the site automatically applies.
5. If the issue is too confusing, there's always the option of placing the work in to the [public domain](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Public_domain)

Some notes on the licenses:

- An article on why everything should be GPL-compatible: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html
- There is a separate issue of **attribution**.  Many licenses require that the code be properly (and appropriately) attributed.  It is for the user (or repackager) to ensure that their reuse of code is properly compliant with the license in this, and other, ways.

When answering this question, please state the terms under which you agree to your code being reused.  Sample statements follow, though you are free to adapt them as required.

**Dual GPL/LPPL:**

> `Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) (version 3 or later) and under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).`

**Permission to relicense:**

> `Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby give permission for it to be used and released under either the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) (version 3 or later) or under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).`

**Public Domain:**

> `Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law.  Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).`

Comment: The point about attribution is that, as I understand it, the LPPL demands an explicit attribution.  GPL is used for the Context source code, and I have the impression that it is the license of choice for Context modules &c.

Comment: @Charles: That's my reading of the LPPL as well.  I figure that the issue of attribution is slightly orthogonal to this discussion.  Even if it's not _required_ by a license, it's only polite to include it.

Comment: GPL is generally a bad idea for software in general, but that's a discussion for another place. It's bad for TeX code because it allows someone to incompatibly modify the code and release it under the same name. As came up elsewhere, I think the ConTeXt folks were _really_ short sighted by refusing to consider the LPPL (or a similar idea just without the L) due to its name alone.

Comment: @TH. If you look at the discussion on 'From Answers to Packages' then Charles' version doesn't have the explicit relicensing as GPL but merely permission to relicense as GPL.

Comment: Public domain clause: Now *that* is crystal clear, nice that something is.

Comment: @Charles: I was going to suggest PD/CC0, by Andrew was faster. I think most code here could be reused under fair use anyway (or is to short to be protected by copyright).

Comment: The statement 'the LPPL and GPL are incompatible' is based on LPPL 1.2. There were a _lot_ of e-mails exchanged between Frank Mittelbach and Debian legal (~1600) to sort things out for LPPL 1.3. Now whether LPPL 1.3 is compatible with the GPL, I have no idea :-)

Comment: I've said before that I'm actually surprised that the site does not make a statement that _all_ code posted here is Public Domain. That's always been the assumption on, for example, c.t.t. (if you post it to a public forum ...).

Comment: @Joseph: (Re LPPL and GPL) My only source is the page on gnu.org where it says that 1.3 has resolved several issue, but it doesn't come to any conclusion.

Comment: +1 for the goons reference

Comment: @Joseph and @Andrew -- re the lppl and gpl in particular, there is an article by frank mittelbach in the issue of tugboat now at the printer (32:1, pp.83-94) that covers this ground.  from the abstract: "This article reflects on the history of the license, the way it came about, and the reasons for its development and content. It explains why it was chosen even though alternative free licenses have been available at least from 1990 onwards."

Comment: @barbara: Thanks.  Almost worth registering with TUG to read it before it goes online next year.

Comment: @JosephWright: _Public Domain_ is a concept you should not use - ask any copyright expert: it's very unclear. BSD is much better.
And code on c.t.t. or anywhere else is copyrighted by the author and you should _not_ use it in commercial projects unless you have a clear license from the author.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I've asked people on c.t.t before about licenses, and got pretty short shrift. There is a _strong_ assumption that anything posted there is 'free' in the broadest sense.

Comment: Also, at least in here in the UK 'public domain' is clear. It means you give up your copyright, in the same way as happens when copyright expires (after a delay) after you die.

Comment: @JosephWright: That assumption is _wrong_. You need an explicit license to use the work of someone else. A post on c.t.t. is only licensed for distribution with NNTP etc., but not for commercial usage.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I think technically you don't need a license but rather permission of the copyright holder (if there is one), which could include copyright transfer. As I said, I've asked for explicit permission in the past on c.t.t. and not come out of it very well. The people concerned were not happy, as they felt that posting in a public forum was pretty clear ("if you don't want people to use your work, don't make it available"). I'm well aware that this may or may not be legally supported, depending on the jurisdiction, but will not be asking them again!

Comment: @JosephWright♦: We can at least be sure that the LPPL 1.3 is [DFSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFSG)-compatible.

Comment: You might also want to link to [TL;DR legal](http://www.tldrlegal.com/)

Comment: Should someone (not me) reorganize the answers to this question so that there are just a few, keyed by the kind of license? Then we could just add our names to existing answers when our wishes matched. Some might want to provide personalized variants.

Comment: For code relicensed under the LPPL, how should clauses 6a, 6d and the procedures for establishing that a work is 'unmaintained' be interpreted for code posted here? I guess my concern is that there are pretty standard procedures for this for code packaged and distributed through ctan, for example, but I'm less clear about how that would work for code here.

Answer (score 17):

**Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the terms of the [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).**

Comment: Please use a once-clause BSD license and not something that will confuse lawyers.

Comment: For material contributed to a Q&A site, I am more concerned with the confusion of non-lawyers and so I chose something that explicitly states the "terms and conditions" in one short sentence. The license I chose grants the freedom to re-license my work if someone finds the original license unacceptable.

Comment: This may sound good to people who have not tried to pick up the pieces but the mess which is created by people not using legally clear licences is not fun to clear up. Packages have been removed from TeX Live due to concerns over licensing. They are removed from Debian (and Fedora and...) for just the same reasons. It doesn't matter how good your intentions. People distributing this stuff have to think about what a court would say if... and a chunk of your code in a derived package could cause that package's removal, whether you want it to or not. Please use something the distros can count on.

Comment: @cfr This is as tested as other licenses. Plus Free Software Foundation recognizes it. Court compatible doesn't mean bloated text. Those licences are also questionable.

Comment: @percusse I was responding to the comment rather than the licence. I know nothing about the legal-acceptability of the licence. My point was that choosing a licence which will satisfy lawyers is important for the interests of non-lawyers, too. Will-keep-lawyers-happy does not need to mean will-confuse-the-rest-of-us. Whether this particular licence fulfils the criteria or not is another question.

Comment: @percusse Also, the FSF lists it but recommends not using it regardless of intentions, although I can't find an explanation of why. Do you know where they explain this?

Comment: @cfr It's based on a hypothetical courtcase interpretation. There is nothing blocking it and it is not court tested so that's just rumor and scaremongering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL#Reception

Comment: @percusse Thanks. You don't know anywhere where FSF give their reasoning, do you? The OSI reasoning seems confused to me, though I may have misunderstood something. (As I understand it, their reasoning is: This licence is no different from public domain. So, better to use public domain instead. Therefore, reject this licence. But public domain does not exist in Europe. Therefore, reject this licence anyway. But why isn't the Europe point a reason not to reject it? I don't see the logic here at all.)

Comment: @cfr First rule of law is that there is no logic to it. By the way, it is only OSI's opinion not a general consensus. If more people adopt it it becomes the norm. Most of these institutions possess self proclaimed validity anyway. I don't know any courtcase regarding these in Europe (not that I thoroughly researched).

Comment: @percusse I think there is logic in most legal systems, albeit a rather twisted and peculiar one at times.  But, really, I was just curious about FSF's reasoning is all. I'm not sure OSI's reasoning is supposed to be legal, but, if it is, that might explain why it seems illogical. (I think there's logic in most legal systems, but not of the logician's kind.)

Comment: The current link is [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/), the one in the question is broken due to age presumably.

Answer (score 13):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/), version 1.3 or later (not author maintained).

Enrico Gregorio

Comment: Would you be so kind to add precisions regarding under which particular version(s) of the LPPL your code is released? My answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485386/73317) contains a `.sty` file that uses code of yours, but it's impossible for me to write a proper license statement in this `.sty` file without knowing this information. Maybe some statement like [mine](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8261/73317)? Thanks.

Comment: @frougon I don't really care, any version of LPPL is good, but just for precision, I added a number.

Answer (score 12):

Any LaTeX/TeX code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) (version 1.3c or later).

Any Perl, Bash or other software programming language code of mine (with the explicit exception of LaTeX/TeX code) that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) (version 3 or later).

Answer (score 11):

**Any TeX code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).**

#### Note Regarding Attribution

Code that is placed in the public domain does not require attribution.  However, if you have found this site useful, the best way to say "*Thank you*" is to point others to it.
So if you wish to acknowledge the source of the code, I recommend a link or bare URL text pointing to somewhere appropriate on this site: if the code came from a single answer, I would link to that answer, but if it is spread over several then a generic link to the site would suffice.

Answer (score 10):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 10):

Any code of mine that I publish or have published previously on the [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) main site I hereby relicense under the [**WTFPL**](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).

Answer (score 10):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 8):

**Any TeX code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law, except when stated otherwise in the corresponding answer. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).**    —Clemens Koppensteiner

For the avoidance of doubt, this only applies to TeX source code. Any other text is not included. Also, while you are not required to do so, you are encouraged to add attribution to any code you use.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea would be to include this in your profile description for maximum visibility.

Comment: @Martin: It isn't important for many people, only package creators.  For them, the fact that users can't make texts here just vanish (they will be visible to 10k+ users even if deleted) is more important.

Answer (score 8):

**Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law, except when stated otherwise in the corresponding answer. Explicitly, I place such code under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).**

#### Note

It is churlish not to attribute public domain code you reuse, but quite legal.

Answer (score 8):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 8):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Attribution  via a link to the relevant answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

My code is highly unlikely to be all *that* useful, but anyway...

**Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).**

Answer (score 7):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

Answer (score 7):

Any code of mine that I publish or have published previously on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

Answer (score 7):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place under the LPPL, version 1.3 or later.

Answer (score 7):

**Any TeX code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).**

#### Note Regarding Attribution

Code that is placed in the public domain does not require attribution.  However, if you have found this site useful, the best way to say "*Thank you*" is to point others to it.
So if you wish to acknowledge the source of the code, I recommend a link or bare URL text pointing to somewhere appropriate on this site: if the code came from a single answer, I would link to that answer, but if it is spread over several then a generic link to the site would suffice.

**Note**: Thank you, [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey), for writing what I wanted to write :-)

Answer (score 6):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 6):

Any LaTeX/TeX code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the LPPL (version 1.3c or later).

Any Perl, Bash or other software programming language code of mine (with the explicit exception of LaTeX/TeX code) that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the GPL (version 3 or later).

Answer (score 6):

Any code (or any stuff for more general) of mine that I publish or have published previously on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ is free as in "free of charge" and "freedom". You can claim it as yours. No attribution or permission is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Any code of mine (TeX, LaTeX, bash, ImageMagick or any other) that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ or in chat rooms associated with the site I hereby give permission for it to be used and released under either [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) license in version 1.3 or higher. The works itself, if applicable, fall into the category "author-maintained". This statement applies for any code published before as well.

This statement does not apply to code I provide to users on this site in a private communication like e-mail, instant messanging (other than the site chat), etc. Such code is only for personal use of the user. The user may ask me to re-license it.

**Tomáš Hejda**

Comment: Could you clarify what steps would be necessary to declare your code unmaintained in the case of non-TeX code (bash, ImageMagick etc.)? Do you intend the same methods of attempted content (which focus on TeX-related communication channels if I remember correctly) to apply to all code, regardless of its TeX-specificity?

Comment: @cfr The author-maintained declaration applies basically only to complete files (such as new `.sty` files that I published here) since the biggest difference between author-maintained and unmaintained is that in the former case you ought to fork the project if you want to modify it. Is it understandable?

Comment: Yes but the real question is what happens if you disappear. Not that I wish you to but the question is what would be necessary to declare code unmaintained in that case. Maybe it is a non-issue and the right thing to say is that for code posted on this site, forking would always be recommended since the disadvantages of forking don't really apply until code is in more general use. (And if you publish a file on ctan or whatever, the usual procedures would be applicable.)

Comment: @cfr Don't you face the very same problem with over 3000 LaTeX packages? Hasn't big packages been forked for the very same reason before? IMHO it is a problem of bigger scale than couple hundred code snippets of mine on this site.

Comment: Well for packages on ctan, there is an established method of determining that the package is 'unmaintained'. Then it can get a new maintainer rather than being forked. I guess I'm just curious as to why LPPL when this doesn't appear to be a particular issue with code here. (That it isn't is kind of my point. Why use a licence which makes a big deal of this when it doesn't really seem relevant?)

Answer (score 6):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the CC0.

Answer (score 5):

Any code of mine that I publish on [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

Claudio

Answer (score 5):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/).

Answer (score 5):

Any TeX code of mine I publish and published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby license as [Beer-Ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beerware). If you reuse it it should contain the following comment:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% "THE BEER-WARE LICENSE" (Revision 42):
% Jonathan P. Spratte  wrote this code.  As long as you retain this notice you
% can do whatever you want with this stuff. If we meet some day, and you think
% this stuff is worth it, you can buy me a beer in return. Jonathan P. Spratte
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any non-TeX code I publish and published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby license under the terms and conditions of the GPL, version 3 of that license or later.

Answer (score 4):

Any code of mine that I publish or have published previously on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

Mikko Korpela

Answer (score 4):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law. Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 4):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

JB

Answer (score 4):

> Any strings of characters, that I posted previously or I will post in the future to this site, automatically belong to you and are not mine. I am not responsible for any gain or loss of using them.
>
> Please refrain from contacting me for granting royalty or attribution. I am not collecting money let alone popularity. I will do an immense deal of good, if I don't care who gets the credit for it.

Comment: welkom to the club :)

Comment: @Raaja: The party has already begun.

Answer (score 4):

Any code of mine that is published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law, except when stated otherwise in the corresponding answer. Explicitly, I place such code under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 4):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law.  Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 3):

Any code or in general anything of mine that I publish or have published previously on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ is free as in "free of charge" and "freedom". You can claim it as yours. No attribution or permission is needed.

May the source be with you.

RGS

Comment: You are very generous, but why should I claim that your software is mine when it is not? (+1 for "may the source be with you").

Comment: @CarLaTeX here I come for fun and learn. Unfortunately, we don't even have the power to hold the higher powers from changing the layout of this site. Hence, I just let it go :P (In a serious note, sometime people do claim that. So, instead of having bad feelings at the end, it's better to relinquish things now).

Comment: Of course, all we are! But if I'm answering a question using some of your code, I think it is correct to say you wrote it. Or, at least, don't say _I_ wrote it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree with you. For instance, initially I was not doing that myself until one day marmot / TeXnician / someone else pointed me out on "how to nice behaviour". So, now  sticking with it.

Comment: Very good, and continue to help us! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sure!

Answer (score 3):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place under the LPPL, version 1.3 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Any code of mine that I have published or will publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ can be used under the terms of the [LaTeX Project Public License](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) either version 1.2 or, at your option, any later version. This license is granted *in addition* to the terms that apply by default to contents published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Florent Rougon

Answer (score 2):

Any code of mine that is published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law, except when stated otherwise in the corresponding answer. Explicitly, I place such code under the CC0.

Answer (score 1):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby place in the public domain to the extent governable by law.  Explicitly, I place it under the [CC0](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0).

Answer (score 0):

Any code of mine that I publish or have ever published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I hereby relicense under the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) (version 2 or later) and under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/).

Answer (score 0):

Any code of mine that I publish on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or any other site of the [stackexchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) I hereby relicense under the [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/).