# Add an additional Licence to "MY" content

Tags: feature-request, design, licensing

following the discussion on licensing, I propose an additional field in the user-profile (this can be a SE-wide thing, or just for TeX.SE, though it would probably fit in Programming.SE as well, as an example).

The idea would be that each user could state that his/her answers and questions would be also placed under an additional licencing agreement. This is important for TeX users since many normal licencing agreements for TeX are incompatible with the GPL, see [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) question for details.

So, in the user profile users would see a choice:

```
My content on TeX.SE is released under:
[ ] Dual GPL/LPPL
[ ] Permission to relicense
[ ] Public Domain
[ ] Normal GPL (default)
with the following modification: <free form text-box>
```

(with links to the definition of each licence)

The other users, when looking at someones user-profile will only see the selected licence and the free-form text.

This is my suggestion.

Comment: Please use BSD instead of [Public Domain](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Public_domain_software).

Answer (score 6):

You can certainly already do this by indicating your license preference is for your posts in your "About Me" field, which is prominently displayed on your user page.

I know I've seen several users do this on a few different Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with showing it in your profile is that there is *no public history* of it. If you post your license statement in the thread [Relicensing code from answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) , the information is there *forever*, with precise dating and timing, which allows to backtrace the correct license for each piece of code you published here.

Answer (score 4):

You can relicense your code by posting answer to [Relicensing code from answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) with your preferred license(s).