# How to give attribution for answers?

Tags: discussion

I've used some answers here to help make figures and do other things in documents I've created.

To make the question specific, consider this question - [drawing oddly shaped nodes to contain existing nodes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274857/drawing-oddly-shaped-nodes-to-contain-existing-nodes-in-tikz) which will affect a figure I'll be publishing soon.

Now the question comes - how do I attribute this?

[This question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) addresses attributing things, but [the license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1) has since been updated.

So my question is basically - do I just need a comment in .tex file saying

```
%this method comes from <url>
```

or do I need something in my bibliography?

or something directly where the figure appears in the text?

Comment: Related (at least for people with an answer on it): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers/4525

Answer (score 13):

I put comments in my source code, and this in the Preface to the book where I thank folks for help.

> Wizards at \url{tex.stackexchange.com} were always quick to answer
>   \TeX{}nical questions.