# What do we do when we see plagiarism of a TexStackExchange answer?

Tags: discussion

Looking for something I found [this website](http://texnorte.blogspot.fr/2013/10/beamer-bibliography-icon.html) claiming that the author write an article[image]. However, this is only a copy paste of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68081/97981 publish one year before.

My question is, what can we do? What we have to do?

Comment: There are others on that site as well: [Local](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132584/5764); [remote](https://texnorte.blogspot.ca/2013/09/transparent-foreground-watermark.html).

Comment: I report it as suggested by the answer. @Werner did you do it also for the pages you mentioned?

Comment: I did not; I merely commented on the post in an attempt to provide some form of original attribution.

Comment: regardless of attribution, at that rate Colombia is the second China, they'll bootleg everything. Speaking of the latter, the other day I checked http://wps-community.org/ and lo and behold , quite impressive, they probably have to iron out hyphenation....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact there is the possibility to report sites which reproduce the content of this site without attribution:

[image]

However in the e-Mail you will receive after reporting such a site, the powers that be are not very optimistic that much can be done.

Answer (score 19):

Nothing in my opinion. There is no ownership claim anyways. And also, the answers here are CC licensed (see the bottom of the page) so the link is only missing attribution. I don't know Gonzalo's point of view but most of us already waived even that requirement in [Relicensing code from answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) (assuming that this re-licensing actually matters). If you are really bothered by this you can place a comment below the page so people can find it back here.

So it is just annoying to not to have the source but I would not go as far as plagiarism although pedanto-technically yes it is. Note that, the whole stackexchange network is duplicated all the time by other websites. Take a popular question search for its text in google and you'll see lots of copy-SE sites.

In general, answering questions here and then claiming ownership of the answers seems a bit contradictory for me. If you are supplying that much of quality in the answer **AND** want to stay as the owner at the same time, then why are you answering a question on a public domain Q&A site. How is it different than

> Look I actually solved your problem, but it's my solution. Ya ain't gettin' it.

Reading a bit more on the list in http://texnorte.blogspot.nl/p/indice-de-post-por-fecha.html we see that the owner mostly skips attribution on TeX-SX answers but the others do have some attribution, thus it might also be the case that the owner thought StackExchange is CC0.

Comment: "so the link is only missing attribution" -- if you were an insistent person you could certainly sue the offender and have good chances of succeeding. Not that there was any money in that except for the lawyers. Personally, I feel that leaving out attribution weighs *especially* heavy if you get the content for free anyways. It's either incredibly lazy or incredibly shameless.

Comment: @Raphael You might need to adjust your accusations for someone trying to help other people on a simple blog. And no you cannot win anything against that person. CC is permissive enough to get away. You can always say you picked them up from SX copy sites etc.

Comment: Also promoting all possible TeX and Friends sites on each page on the right bar in his blog. I would say you are being lazy for generalizing every mis-attribution to plagiarism.

Comment: Maybe I was overly optimistic from a creator point of view. (I did not look at the special case.) In any case, even if "only attribution" is missing -- which is *everything* CC requires! -- there clearly is a license violation which I don't think should be trivialized.